# unexpected token import whit babel

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

i guess my webpack somehow doesnt transpile with babel as a loader and i get the exception,

i have babel-core ,babel-presets-es2015, babel-loader installed i configured a .babelrc file with presets of es2015

i run webpack.server and all goes smoothly then i try to run build\server it shows this exception
added my webpack config and dependencies
thank you

```
var path = require("path");
function createConfig(isDebug) {
    return {
        target: "node",
        devtool: "source-map",
        entry: "./src/server/server.js",
        output:{
            path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
            filename: "server.js"
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                shared: path.join(__dirname, "src", "shared")
            }
        },
        module:{
            loaders: [
                {test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
                {test: /\.js$/, loader: "eslint-loader", exclude: /node_modules/     }
            ]
        }
    };
}
module.exports = createConfig(true);
module.exports.create = createConfig;
```

```
and this is the dependencies

<code>
{
  "name": "3d-web-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "eslint": "^3.12.2",`enter code here`
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
</code>
```

Comment: Please post your code as text. An image of code is not considered code, it's an image.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: added the code tnx

Answer (score 0):

#### You might have to add `query:{presets:["es2015"]}` to the *config*

```
...
module:{
  loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: "babel-loader", 
      exclude: /node_modules/, 
      query:{
        presets:["es2015"]
      } 
    },
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: "eslint-loader", 
      exclude: /node_modules/     
    }
  ]
}
...
```

Good Luck.